# How to get a pre-release linux kernel to work with SecureBoot (Fedora 26)

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, kernel, secure-boot

I'm running Fedora 26, but to get suspend and resume working, I need to use a Rawhide kernel (4.13.rc-1 or later) ([See kernel issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192591#c95)).

I've successfully installed the Rawhide kernel (4.13.rc-4) using [these instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/RawhideKernelNodebug). Unfortunately as that page note, these kernels will not work seamlessly without having SecureBoot disabled.

Unfortunately due to a BIOS bug, I can't disable SecureBoot ([See Dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/20009547)).

When I try to boot, the bootloader says something like:

> ...has an invalid signature. You will need to load the kernel first.

How can I use a Rawhide / pre-release kernel with SecureBoot enabled?

Comment: If you want more background details about my situation I've been documenting them all [here](https://jasono.co/2017/08/13/tricks-i-needed-to-install-fedora-26-on-a-dell-xps-13-9365-2-in-1/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you might consider asking the Fedora kernel team if they'd be willing to backport the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and edit!) @mattdm.  Any ideas what the best way is to make a request to the fedora kernel team?  IRC / mailing list etc.  I'm new to the Fedora community so still learning the best way to get in contact

Comment: I'd start with Bugzilla, and then if that doesn't get noticed (there are a lot of bugs to triage!), post to the [Fedora Kernel mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/admin/lists/kernel.lists.fedoraproject.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered on Fedora's Q&A site:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/109564/how-to-get-rawhide-kernel-to-work-with-secureboot-in-f26/?answer=109840#post-id-109840

Basically:

- As root, run `mokutil --disable-validation` and set a password.
- Reboot, and when grub loads it will ask if you want to run the MOK util.  I had to press a key within 10 seconds to make sure I entered the utiltiy.
- Once in the utility, I choose "modify MOK config", entered the password, and chose to disable SecureBoot. Note this didn't disable the BIOS SecureBoot - it just allows GRUB to load an unsigned kernel.  (GRUB is still signed I guess).

Answer (score 1):

I realize you've found a solution that involves disabling Secure Boot via Shim/`mokutil`; however, there is another way: You can sign the kernel yourself.

In broad outline, the procedure is:

1. Generate your own Secure Boot key. You'd do this with the `openssl` program. You'll need to copy the public key DER file to your EFI System Partition (ESP), which is normally mounted at `/boot/efi`.
2. Sign your kernel file. I use a tool called `sbsign` to do this. IIRC, Fedora favors another program that, the last I checked, was more complex to use. You'll need to either rename the current kernel and put your signed version in its place or create a new GRUB entry for your new kernel.
3. Reboot into the EFI and launch MokManager. Some boot loaders, like my own rEFInd, offer a way to enter MokManager manually. If yours doesn't, you may need to jump through some hoops to get it working. Once in MokManager, you need to locate the DER file you copied to the ESP and add it to your MOK list.
4. At this point, when you reboot you should be able to launch your newly-signed kernel even with Secure Boot active.

This procedure is covered in more detail on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#shim) It's tedious, and may not be worth the effort compared to disabling Secure Boot -- but then again, maybe it is. You'll have to make the judgment call of whether you want to jump through these hoops to keep booting with Secure Boot active.

Note also that if you install rEFInd, it may generate a set of Secure Boot keys and store them as `/etc/refind.d/keys/refind_local.*`. (The `refind-install` script does this if the necessary utilities are available, but won't do so if they aren't available.) Thus, if you've ever installed rEFInd, step #1 may already be done. You can then use the local rEFInd key to sign your kernel.

There's a variant of this procedure, too. Recent versions of Shim and MokManager enable you to register a binary's hash as a way to authenticate it. This works even with unsigned binaries. Thus, you could register your kernel's hash to enable it to boot. The trouble with this is that you'll need to register the hash of every unsigned kernel you want to launch. This may not be a big deal if you've got just the one working kernel and you don't plan to update it; but if you update the kernel every couple of weeks, you'll be forever registering new hashes, which will both be a hassle and consume increasing amounts of limited NVRAM space. Thus, this approach is a bit easier in some cases but is much worse in others.

Comment: This is really impressive - and was the answer I had been hoping to find, but couldn't get clear instructions on.  Thanks for taking the time to document it!  Sadly I've given up on the laptop I was trying to do this with, so I can't actually try it out.  But I appreciate it anyway!